# Save Google NGram result as .csv

Tags: csv, n-gram

Is there an easy way, to save a Google Ngram result
http://books.google.com/ngrams/
as a csv?

So that I get a list like

```
1900 peace 500000times
1901 peace 540000times
```

and so on?

I downloaded their raw data but have no idea how to handle it. When I open those csv in OpenOffice, I can't even see a single word.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done, and it's actually quite easy. Generate the graph you want on the Google Ngram viewer, then use your browser's function to show the page source code (this might be hidden under advanced or developer options). Then in the code (probably on line 297), you will find the data simply listed. You can use any word processor and/or spreadsheet software to clean up the data and export them as CSV.

Comment: I used Notepad++ replace option to replace all "," with \n in Regular Expression mode. This puts all the data into a single column so you can open in your application as any other text file.

Answer (score 2):

No, you'd have to go to [their datasets](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets), which would be daunting to find what you wanted, or you could try Microsoft Research's [N-Gram service](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/info/).